# Why doesn't the Continuum Hypothesis show that $\text{ZFC}$ is simply consistent?

Tags: set-theory, incompleteness

Where is my error?

A system is simply inconsistent is every formula is provable (if $\text{A} \wedge\neg \text{A}$ were provable for some formula $\text{A}$, then by $\neg$-introduction, any formula can be proven).  Taking the contraposition, we get that if there exist some formula that is unprovable, the system is simply consistent.

Since the Continuum Hypothesis is undecidable and thus unprovable in $\text{ZFC}$, shouldn't that mean that $\text{ZFC}$ is simply consistent?  This also shows the other direction of Gödel's first theorem: if the system is incomplete, then it is consistent.

I know all of this can't be right because I haven't read any of this and it can't be that easy, so I must be missing something.

Comment: What we know about the continuum hypothesis is that *if ZFC is consistent* then it proves neither CH nor its negation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The think you're missing is the conditional part of undecidability of CH: it is undecidable, *provided ZFC is consistent*.

Roughly, the proof goes like this: we start with an arbitrary model of ZFC (which we have if ZFC is consistent), and then the constructible universe L within is a model of ZFC+CH, while an appropriate Cohen forcing extension is a model of ZFC+$\neg$CH.

None of this makes any sense if we have no model of ZFC to begin with.

Comment: +1 - to the OP, note that one additional step here is the **completeness theorem**, which lets us go from a consistent theory to a model of that theory. So a "background theory" capable of making sense of forcing - and $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is massive overkill for that - can prove "If $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is consistent, then $\mathsf{ZFC}$ has a model and so $\mathsf{ZFC+CH}$ and $\mathsf{ZFC+\neg CH}$ each have models and hence are consistent." One subtlety here is that consistency does *not* give us the existence of a well-founded model, so we either have to do some reflection-based shenanigans *(contd)*

Comment: or, in my opinion more naturally, just develop forcing over arbitrary countable models (or even arbitrary models, via Boolean-valued structures).